# Removing multiple occurences of a node in an XMLNodeList or combobox

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

My objective is to search an XML document for particutar nodeS and populate a combobox with those nodes' Id's.  I can do this by using the folloing:

```
        XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//NodeA");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
     {
         comboBox1.Items.Add(node.Attributes["id"].Value);
     }
```

My problem is this.  There are multiple occurances of the Xpath "//NodeA" with the same ID attribute.  Therefore I end up populating the combobox with multiple occurances of these node IDs.  I only want one of each in the combo box.

Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!comboBox1.Items.Contains(node.Attributes["id"].Value))
{
 comboBox1.Items.Add(node.Attributes["id"].Value);
}
```

Comment: you are welcome, mark my answer as response to close the thread.